# Degree of a morphism between affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, notation

(Context: rewriting a joint paper with a coauthor.)

We are defining the degree of a morphism $f:A^m\to A^{n}$ to be $\max_{1\leq i\leq n} \deg(f_i)$, for $f_1,f_2,\dotsc,f_{n}$ the polynomials defining $f$. Then we define the degree of $f:X\to Y$ (for affine varieties $X\subset A^m$, $Y\subset A^{n}$) to be the minimum of $\deg(\overline{f})$ over all $\overline{f}:\mathbb{A}^{m}\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^{n}$ with $\overline{f}|_{X}=f$. This is *not* the same as the standard definition of degree for finite morphisms.

(1) Is this evil/illiterate?

(2) Shall we call our "degree" something else (what exactly?)?

Comment: Perhaps "complexity" or "degree of definition"?

Comment: Hm. "Degree of definition" (degdef?) makes it sound like the degree depends on the definition, but it doesn't; we are taking a minimum of $\deg(\overline{f})$.

Comment: The name is by analogy with "field of definition", which is also a minimum, not depending on a particular definition. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_definition). So for readers familiar with that concept you should be OK, but I agree it might be problematic for others.

Comment: Hm, that's not what was immediately brought to my mind by degree of definition. Someone else suggests "maximal degree", but that may be more confusing - suggesting that one is taking a maximum over the range or the domain, no?

Comment: Maybe "polynomial degree" (poldeg)?

Comment: Algebraic Degree?

Comment: The other definition (for finite morphisms) is also algebraic, no?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) maxdegree (one word).

Comment: I think we'll settle for calling it "maximum degree" and denoting it my $\mdeg$, where \mdeg is defined as \textrm{mdeg}. Or is that not good?

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but you might want to clarify what $\operatorname{deg}(0)$ is. If all $f_i$ are zero, the map does not appear to be "worse" than any other constant map, but with [typical definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Degree_of_the_zero_polynomial), you end up with a negative degree (as opposed to degree $0$ for other constant maps).

Comment: On second thought, "maxdegree" might be a good name. Can anybody come up with an argument against it?